# Vector index: cannot move out of dereference

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn Rust by implementing a few basic data structures. In this case, a `Matrix`.

```
struct Matrix<T> {
  pub nrows: uint,
  pub ncols: uint,
  pub rows: Vec<T>
}
```

Now, I want to transpose a `Matrix` using this function:

```
pub fn transpose(&self) -> Matrix<T> {
  let mut trans_matrix = Matrix::new(self.ncols, self.nrows);
  for i in range(0u, self.nrows - 1u) {
    for j in range(0u, self.ncols - 1u) {
      trans_matrix.rows[j*i] = self.rows[i*j]; // error
    }
  }
  trans_matrix
}
```

But I get this error on the marked line:

```
error: cannot move out of dereference (dereference is implicit, due to indexing)
error: cannot assign to immutable dereference (dereference is implicit, due to indexing)
```

So what I have to do is make the `rows` of `trans_matrix` mutable, and somehow fix the dereference error. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
*trans_matrix.rows.get_mut(j * i) = self.rows[i * j];
```

works, but is only a workaround. I don't know how long it will take until `IndexMut` works as intended, or if it already does, but this was *the preferred way* some time ago.

Comment: Believe it or not, I still have the same error: `error: cannot move out of dereference (dereference is implicit, due to indexing) *trans_matrix.rows.get_mut(j * i) = self.rows[i * j];`. Also, `get_mut()` is marked as deprecated (use indexing).

Comment: @tolgap: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/041f42520620cafe6c1c) compiles with my setup, even though it complains about dead code. Please test it.

Comment: that code is not compiling for me (same error). I'm using `rustc 0.12.0-nightly (c669411af)`

Comment: `rustc -v`: `rustc 0.12.0-nightly (2550243b4 2014-09-25 19:02:44 +0000)` for me. Also, I changed the link in the above comment some seconds after I posted it, because I pasted the wrong link into it, assuming you'd take more than these few seconds to read the comment. You absolutely tried to compile [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/041f42520620cafe6c1c) gist, right?

Comment: Actually, I was F5'ing so I caught the previous link. Your edit works. I think the cause was in my `Matrix::new` function, where I created a mutable `rows` variable for the `Matrix` struct. When I changed that, it worked!